# OpenGL ES sphere issues

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I've been following the tutorials http://www.learnopengles.com and learning more how to work with OpenGL ES but I'm having a hard time trying to get a sphere to show up.

I've went ahead and made a geodesic sphere in Blender and imported the vertices and the draw order but I whenever I call the sphere the app crashes.

I'll include a link to my full render file but I'll also point out what I think some of the key things where I think problems might be:

Here is where the buffers are created. I'm not sure if the app has issues with the way I'm buffering the sphere or the sphere's draw order points.

```
// Initialize the buffers.
    mCubePositions = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(cubePositionData.length * mBytesPerFloat)
    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();                            
    mCubePositions.put(cubePositionData).position(0);

    mSpherePositions = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(spherePositionData.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    mSpherePositions.put(spherePositionData).position(0);

    ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(sphereDrawOrder.length * 2).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
    drawListBuffer.put(sphereDrawOrder);
    drawListBuffer.position(0);


    mCubeColors = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(cubeColorData.length * mBytesPerFloat)
    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();                            
    mCubeColors.put(cubeColorData).position(0);

    mCubeNormals = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(cubeNormalData.length * mBytesPerFloat)
    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();                            
    mCubeNormals.put(cubeNormalData).position(0);
```

And here is the class that draws the sphere. I have no colors or normals for the sphere so I just removed those parts. Is that what's causing it to freak out?

```
private void drawSphere()
{       
    // Pass in the position information
    mSpherePositions.position(0);       
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, mPositionDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            0, mSpherePositions);        

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);        

    // Pass in the color information


    // Pass in the normal information


    // This multiplies the view matrix by the model matrix, and stores the result in the MVP matrix
    // (which currently contains model * view).
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);   

    // Pass in the modelview matrix.
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);                

    // This multiplies the modelview matrix by the projection matrix, and stores the result in the MVP matrix
    // (which now contains model * view * projection).
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);

    // Pass in the combined matrix.
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);

    // Pass in the light position in eye space.        
    GLES20.glUniform3f(mLightPosHandle, mLightPosInEyeSpace[0], mLightPosInEyeSpace[1], mLightPosInEyeSpace[2]);

    // Draw the sphere.
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, sphereDrawOrder.length,
            GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);                              
}
```

Whenever it crashes it tells me there's something wrong with the code after //Draw the sphere. It doesn't like the glDrawElements for some reason.

Here is the full render script for reference: http://pastebin.com/Y1WU27hz

If you have any insight to this I thank you.

Comment: What is your crash message telling you? Have you tried to poll for errors with glGetError? Does the cube work if you draw it?

Comment: It's giving me a typical "App has crashed error" and LogCat is telling me it's a runtime error on lines 564 and 478 which are the drawSphere() call and the glDrawElements

Comment: Are you drawing the sphere only, or attempting to draw the cube and the sphere?

Comment: Sphere only. If you replace drawSphere() with drawCube() it works fine. The tutorial covers the cube, but I want to make a sphere.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure then, the code looks right to me. Posting the exact logcat error may help, but I'm not certain.

Comment: 08-19 21:34:02.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2741):  at com.atonea.SpaceRisk.SRTrenderer.drawSphere(SRTrenderer.java:568)


08-19 21:34:02.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2741):  at com.atonea.SpaceRisk.SRTrenderer.onDrawFrame(SRTrenderer.java:478)